# Which gtk3 widget is this?

Tags: user-interface, themes, gtk3

I want to put a 1px border on [this](http://ubuntuone.com/6mTSrUTIeQ4uO9X5ftsAwM) widget, but can't find the name for it.

Comment: I will point to "Read the code, Luke" post frmo Jeff Atwood, but I'm too lazy to search for the URI. In the mean time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a **GtkTreeView** probably inside a **GtkScrolledWindow**, for being sure, look at the comment before.

Comment: Yes that looks like it thanks. It was hard to tell from the css.